# Resolve integral with importance sample Monte Carlo

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, monte-carlo

I'm trying to compute the integral 
$$\int_{a}^{b}(\sin( 1 + x ) + \cos( 1 + x ))e^{-x}\ dx$$

using importance sample Monte Carlo method.
The exercise ask to use Cauchy Distribution to resolve the integral.
Then
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n}\frac{f(x_i)}{g(x_{i})}$$
is an aproximation to the integral, where $g(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$(Cauchy distribution). To generate random numbers in a range $[a, b]$ following Cauchy distribution I used the inverse transformation:
$$X = \tan(\arctan(a) + U(\arctan(b)-\arctan(a)))\quad \Rightarrow\quad \ U \sim(0,1)$$

but I did not get success.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
The probability distribution which is normalized in $\ds{\left[a,b\right)}$ is given by:
$$
{\rm P}\pars{x} = {1 \over \arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a}}\,{1 \over x^{2} + 1}
$$

> $$
> \int_{a}^{x}{\rm P}\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi = \int_{0}^{U}\dd U'\quad\imp\quad
> {\arctan\pars{X} - \arctan\pars{a} \over \arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a}}
> =U
> $$
>   which leads to
>   $\ds{\arctan\pars{X}
>      =\arctan\pars{a} + \bracks{\arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a}}U}$:
>   \begin{align}
> X = \tan\pars{\arctan\pars{a} + \bracks{\arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a}}}
> ={a + \tan\pars{\bracks{\arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a}}U}
> \over 1 - a\tan\pars{\bracks{\arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a}}U}}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\fermi\pars{x_{i}} \approx
N\int_{a}^{b}{\rm P}\pars{x}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x 
$$

$$
\int_{a}^{b}{\fermi\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1} \approx
{\arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a} \over N}\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\fermi\pars{x_{i}}
$$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#000}{\large%
> \int_{a}^{b}\bracks{\sin\pars{1 + x} + \cos\pars{1 + x}}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&\approx\color{#00f}{\large%
> {\arctan\pars{b} - \arctan\pars{a} \over N}\times}
> \\[3mm]&\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{i = 1}^{N}
> \bracks{\sin\pars{1 + x_{i}} + \cos\pars{1 + x_{i}}}\expo{-x_{i}}
> \pars{x_{i}^{2} + 1}}
> \end{align}
>   with $\ds{\braces{x_{i}}}$ generated by $\pars{1}$ and associated $\ds{\braces{U_{i}}}$ generated by an uniform distribution in $\ds{\left[0,1\right)}$.

Comment: thanks very much for the help. For example if I wanted to use the exponential distribution, it would be normalized in [a, b] is given by: 
$P(x) = \frac{e^{-x + a}}{e^{-b} - e^{-a}}$.Sorry about that more this question is that I'm comparing the distributions

Comment: @user50098 You're welcome. Sorry it's quite late.